# Is there a "super font" to simulate a typewriter?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2010, emulator

I need to have a realistical output, as if I had typed with a typewriter.

For this a font is not enough, I found many of them at [this address](http://simplythebest.net/fonts/typewriter_fonts.html) but they are just fonts.

I need something more, like a "font" that has 5 or 10 different images for each letter. So every time I type "R" I have a random "R", if there are 5 samples they will be randomly extracted. Does this exist?

Moreover I would like to have some random spacing... so that the final result really seems made with a typewriter.

Is there a super font or may be there is a word option for activating randomness, or some dedicated emulator?

Comment: Given that the first suggestion of [Forensic examination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter#Forensic_examination) of typewriters was in 1891, I think you should be fairly safe (typographically speaking) with any single typewriter font, since impressions seem to be pretty consistent for the same character from the same machine. *8')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tl;dr: [FF Trixie](http://trixiefont.com/)

> But the real advancement is found in FF Trixie HD, which contains
>   seven alternates for each character, each with its own weight and
>   texture. Just like typewritten forms, the letters dance on the
>   baseline and reveal the effect of ink on the ribbon. Van Blokland
>   didn’t stop there. Playing with OpenType’s ability to automatically
>   substitute glyphs, he added a variety of clever effects such as more
>   erratic baseline shifting, both true and faux Greek and Cyrillic, and
>   censor simulation.

---

> **Is there a super font**

My first thought was: "fonts don't have the capabilities (unless someone unusually obsessive does something exceptionally clever in true-type hinting)" but it turns out I am wrong, there are [fonts with some of the features you seek](http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~luc/randomizedfonts.html):

> With Bernard Desruisseaux we developed a randomized PostScript type 3
>   font in 1996 that incorporates various interesting parameter choices.
>   Because of its conceptual closeness with Knuth's Metafont, Bernard's
>   font family is called MetamorFont. This font introduces randomness in
>   every glyph, a nice feature of type 3 fonts not available in truetype
>   or type 1. Bernard finished about three glyphs per week, because each
>   glyph is an intricate program that had to be tested and retested. The
>   font has six major multiple master axes or parameters: the amount of
>   randomness, the stress angle, the contrast ratio, the stroke
>   thickness, the outline mode, and the jumpiness of the glyphs. There
>   are ten minor parameters, for a total of 9132 lines of PostScript
>   code. For each setting of the parameters, the font is fully random:
>   each glyph produced is never repeated!

.

> Partially discussed here by John Butler, the Randomize feature in
>   Opentype allows a cyclic substitution of glyphs by other ones, for
>   example, to create the feel of randomness if each glyph has several
>   slighty different implementations. This principle dates from the late
>   80s, when Signature Software first tried it in its handwritten font
>   software. Those were type 3 fonts where such things were easy to do.
>   Of course, "randomize" is not the right word. As of early 2006, no
>   major software supports OpenType's "randomize" feature, but John
>   Butler managed to get around it using the Contextual Alternates feature.

.

> **or may be there is a word option for activating randomness,**

It's such a specialised idea that I imagine it is unlikely to be a standard option in a conventional mass-market word processor. (This is an evasive way of saying I don't know)

> **or some dedicated emulator?**

Well, you can rasterise the output and post-process it with an image manipulation tool. Heres [an example](http://www.xach.com/gimp/tutorials/rough.html)

Comment: +1 and I think after all that reasearch you deserve at least 5% of any ransom that Zonder gets after delivering their note.

Comment: @Linker3000 definitely. If thanks to FF Trixie I get all the sum I'm asking for I think I can give 10% to RedGrittyBrick and devolve 5% to SuperUser.com... :) :) :) Thanks!